# Play/audio icons not showing

Tags: mediaelement.js

The play and audio icons are not showing in the audio bar. I can hover my mouse where the Play button should be and the tool tip says "Play/Pause".  Clicking there starts the audio playing as it should.  But the Play icon (arrow) is not showing.

I read the responses in another post and have tried them:

- I do not have a CSS style being applied to buttons
- I have double-checked that the image paths are correct and that both graphic files "controls.svg" and "controls.png" are on the server.
- I uploaded the exact same set of mediaelement test files to 2 different servers -- on one server the icons display fine, on the other they do not show.

I'm not sure what to try next.

Comment: You may use Firebug to get more detail on what is happening...

Comment: Mediaelement uses div blocks as buttons. Do you apply CSS rules on immediate element tags, such as div? Which browsers exhibit that behavior?

Comment: Thanks for your comments!  I have noticed that only Internet Explorer is showing the play buttons.  But IE is not showing the loading/status bar in the middle of the player.  They do not appear on FF, Chrome or any Mac browser. I am using CSS rules on divs, yes.  The page I'm working with right now is at http://roso.co/audio/ The mediaelement audio player I'm trying to get to look correct is underneath the video.  I'll try commenting out some of my DIV rules just to see if any of them allow the audio player to display the play  buttons.

Comment: Rob, did you ever fix this issue?  Please post, as I have a similar problem.